# Remove motion blur with real time performance on camera input

Tags: python, opencv, video, deconvolution, motion-blur

I have drawn simple pattern of geometrical shapes on a paper and placed it one a object as marker. I'm able to detect and analyze pattern successfully. However when object moves a little faster the motion blur is introduced which can be rotational or linear. This way detected regions overlap e.g. a strip of arrows moving in direction of arrows, is detected as a single line after introduction of motion blur. Therefore I need to fix it somehow. So I can detect individual arrows and analyze them.
Below are images of markers with and without motion blur.

[image]

[image]

Is there any python module or open source implementation that can be used to solve it?
Motion can be in any direction at any speed so PSF is not known and required for Wiener, Lucy-Richardson methods. 
Also it is a realtime tracking problem so I need something that executes fast.

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7 and Opencv 3

Comment: Could you perhaps improve your lighting and capture with significantly shorter exposure time? | It might be useful to provide some example images along with your question.

Comment: @DanMašek Please check out the images posted above. Ignore the green lines.

Comment: Your motion blur is not uniform linear.  There is some curvature. So that is not easy to detect nor recover with the tools in OpenCV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved by limiting the exposure time of your camera. This can be done using opencv by using:
 `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,40)`
or using the v4l2-ctl command line utility.

Answer (score 1):

1. first step is to check whether camera is suitable for opencv properties such as

   ```
   CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH 
   CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
   ```

   in order to check camera suitability
2. second step is to is use `CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE` like

   ```
   cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 40)
   ```

   value can be change accordingly to avoid motion blur